# Embedding Localized Resources for a JavaScript File In ASP.NET

Tags: javascript, asp.net, resx, webresource

I want to embed my resource file in my javascript file.

I have:

- *global.resx*
- *main.js*
- *default.aspx*

Added this to the assembly.cs:

*[assembly: System.Web.UI.WebResource("main.js", "application/x-javascript")]*

*[assembly: System.Web.UI.ScriptResource("main.js", "Resources.Global", "Resources")]*

Changed main.js to embed resource

***I did exactly as stated here:*** [Embedding Localized Resources for a JavaScript File](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398868.aspx)

But I still get that Resources is "undefined" in my js.